# Some doubts in hibernate mutiple choice

Tags: hibernate

Need expert help to clear my exam . Please help.   Please provide the answer to these questions if you are an expert. :) Thanks in advance

```
Q1)If you are trying session scope with regular spring IoC container such as XmlBeanFactory or ClassPathXmlApplication context which exception you will get ?
a)classcast Exception
b)Illegal Exception
c)BeanCreationException
d)Bean Exception

Q2)we configure a bean from ___________class in spring bean documents to get ‘session factory’ of ‘Hibernate’
a)session factory
b)Session Bean factory 
c)local session bean factory
d)session bean


Q3)In Spring , where will you define the bean factories ?
a)BeanRefContext.xml
b)businessApplicationContext.xml
c)spring.xml
d)application.xml


Q4)which attribute in <bean> tag instructs  the container to instantiate the bean only when getBean(“beanid”) is invoked ?
a)abstract
b)lazy-init
c)scope
d)init-method
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about exam questions

Answer (score 0):

1. (I did not undrstand what you are asking). Could be bean creation exception
2. local session factory bean (C)
3. businessApplicationContext.xml (B)
4. lazy-init (b)